# Core Data Query Multiple Columns with Single Search String

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, core-data

I have a simple Core Data model with two string attributes (size and category). Given a search string like 'small widget' is it possible to return records that match all the query words to at least one attribute (i.e. all records with 'small' size and 'widget' category)? I currently have:

```
NSString *search = @"small widget"
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"size contains[cd] %@ OR category contains[cd] %@", search, search];
...
```

This won't return any results (as no category or size equals "small widget"). Any suggestions? Note that the search strings will be user entered from a text field and may come in any order so I can't split up manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it but it looks like your want this:

```
NSString *search = @"small widget";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ contains[cd] size AND %@ contains[cd] category", search, search];
```

The search string would contain (or not) the size and the category, you should ask if the current size or category is contained on the search string.

You could also split the search string and modify your predicate. You should them to identify the one that performs better

```
NSString *search = @"small widget";
    NSArray *array = [search componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSMutableArray *subPredicates = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *q in array) {
        [subPredicates addObject:
         [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"size contains[cd] %@ OR category contains[cd] %@", q, q]];
    }
    NSCompoundPredicate *predicate = [[[NSCompoundPredicate alloc] initWithType:NSAndPredicateType
                                                                 subpredicates:subPredicates] autorelease];
```

Comment: For the first example, wouldn't this match a 'large widget' when the query is 'small widget'?

Comment: Also, I think the second has the same problem.

Comment: How about using NSAndPredicateType instead of NSOrPredicateType? So, you would have (((size contains 'small') **OR** (category contains 'small')) **AND** ((size contains 'widget') **OR** (category contains 'widget'))).

Comment: As I've said, I haven't tested it. Although I think you are right. On the first example I've used and AND, and so the string should contain both components to be true, and on the second one, a NSAndPredicateType would do the job. Cheers, vfn

Answer (score 1):

For Swift you can fetch multiple columns by using **propertiesToFetch**

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "<YOUR ENTITY NAME>")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "<YOUR PREDICATE>")
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType


// Here is where you can query multiple columns, you can add as much columns as you want and fetch them as an array of dictionaries
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["column1", "column2", "column3, "column4"]


let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "column1", ascending: false)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
```